# The convolution is in $L^1$

Tags: lp-spaces, distribution-theory, convolution

According to my notes:

The convolution is in $L^1$. Indeed

$$\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) g(x-y) dy\right) dx\right| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y) g(x-y)| dx dy= ||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} ||g||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$

First of all, the formula of the convolution is this:

$$(f \ast g) (x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) g(x-y) dy$$

So in order to show that the convolution is in $L^1$ why do we take a double integral?

Also why does it hold that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y) g(x-y)| dx dy= ||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} ||g||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ ?

Don't we have that $||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)| dx$ and $||g||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |g(x)| dx$ ?

**EDIT**: Could you explain to me why we can use Fubini?

Comment: we are looking at the $L^1$ norm of $f \ast g$. and for proving $\|f \ast g\|_{L^1} \le\| \ |f| \ast |g| \ \|_{L^1} =  \|f\|_{L^1}\|g\|_{L^1}$ apply the change of variable $v = x-y$

Comment: And we also have to apply Fubini. In order to do so we have to show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y)| |g(x-y)| dy dx<+\infty$, right? @user1952009

Comment: Fubini if you want, I prefer to say that everything is absolutely convergent, hence no problem for inverting $\int . dy$ and $\int . dx$

Comment: But don't we have to show that everything is absolutely convergent? @user1952009

Comment: it is obvious that everything is... say if $n=1$ : $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| \int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(y-x)| dy dx = \| g\|_{L^1} \|f\|_{L^1}$

Comment: But in our case we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y)| |g(x-y)| dy dx$. In order to use that what you say we would have to use Fubini. Or not? @user1952009

Comment: no ! you don't have to USE fubini because proving it is obvious here ! write that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) g(y-x) dx dy = r(A) + \int_{-A}^A \int_{-A}^A f(x) g(y-x) dx dy$ $ = r(A) +\int_{-A}^A \int_{-A}^A f(x) g(y-x) dy dx = r(A) + s(A) + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) g(y-x) dy dx$ where $r(A)$ and $s(A)$ are the residuals that $\to 0$ as $A \to \infty$...

Comment: and this is exactly the same process for exchanging two limits : when everything converges nicely, it is not complicated

Comment: I haven't understood why we get $r(A)$ and $s(A)$. Doesn't it hold that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) g(y-x) dx dy= \lim_{A \to +\infty} \int_{-A}^{A} \int_{-A}^A f(x) g(y-x) dx dy$ ? @user1952009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in order to show that the function $f \ast g$ is in $L^1$ we just have to integrate its absolute value over the variable, in this case over $x$.
For the detailed calculation consider
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}| (f \ast g)(x)| dx=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) g(x-y) dy\right| dx \\ 
\leq& \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y) g(x-y)| \;dy\; dx\\ 
=& \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y)| | g(x-y)| \;dy\; dx\\ =&\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y)|\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  | g(x-y)|\; dx\right)\; dy \\ =&\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y)|\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  | g(v)| \;dv\right)\; dy\\ =&\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y)|\|g\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} \;dy \\ =& ||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} ||g||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

where we used Fubini to interchange $dx,dy$ and we substituted $x-y$ with $v$.

Comment: I understand :) In order to use Fubini, don't we have to show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y)| |g(x-y)| dy dx<+\infty$ ?

Comment: Maybe it will help you to read about Tonelli's theorem (which is almost identical to Fubini, sometimes even stated as Fubini), that says, that it is enough that your function depending on $x$ and $y$ is non-negative. You don't need the assumption that the integral converges.

Comment: Doesn't it also require that the integrals are finite? @Valentin

Comment: No, that's exactly the helpful part of this theorem by Tonelli. You may read more on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions

Comment: So since we consider the absolute value of the function , it is non-negative and so we can interchange $dx, dy$, right?

Comment: Exactly, this is also quite useful for infinite sums. Only when negative terms are involved in the sums the interchanging of the sums can have non welcomed consequences. Otherwise everything is perfectly nice.